# Is it possible to create a dual-boot setup AFTER fully installing Xubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu

The title pretty much says it all. I apologize if this is a dumb question, I've searched around and found nothing thus far. I still have access to the Xubuntu live flash drive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: It's a perfectly valid question but then, if you're asking, you better learn the basics before even starting to think about doing it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Not sure why you made that comment. I do know what I am doing, but got hung up on some of the details. The link that karel posted helped fill in some of the gaps. To be fair, it says I am a "new contributor" but I made a new account.